# Is $A_n$ isomorphic to $C_n$ in general

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $A_n$ denote the alternating group of order $n$, and let $C_n$ be the cyclic group of order $n$. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I know that $A_3 = \{(),(1,2,3),(1,3,2)\}\cong \{0,1,2\}=C_3$. I'm not really sure why, but I'm just accepting it. Is it true in general that $A_n\cong C_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$

Comment: No way. In fact, if this were true then any polynomial equation could be solved in radicals.

Comment: ah I see, so is this only true for $n=3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, It is not.

$A_4$ has $12$ elements so It can not ismomorphic to $C_4$ !. But Actually, $A_n$ is not even abelian for $n\geq 4$.

Comment: I'm new to the alternating groups and I'm aware that they are a subset of $S_n$ consisting of permutations with an even number of transpositions. But then why is $(1,2,3)\in A_3$. Doesn't that have an odd number of transpositions

Comment: @AndrewBrick: $(1,2,3)=(1,3)(1,2)$. Hence, it is even.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how can you break the permutation  down like that? is it true that $(1,2,...,n)=(1,n)(1,n-1)...(1,2)$ in general

Comment: Because $(1,3,2) = (1,2)(3,2)$ but I thought it would be $(1,2)(1,3)$

Comment: @AndrewBrick: Yes , it is true in general.